# How to add JLabel in JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jinternalframe

I have a HTML table in Jlabel(java),I want to display JLabel in JInternalFrame
or I want to add small HTML table into Jinternalframe without JLabel.
how can I achieve ? I want JLabel in place of header not in the body.

```
    package code;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    class JInternalFrameTest extends JFrame {

        JInternalFrameTest()
        {
            setTitle("JInternalFrame");
            setJInternalFrame();
            setSize(700,300);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        void setJInternalFrame()
        {
            String htmlContent = "<html><body><table border = '1'>";
            htmlContent += "<tr><td>Hai</td></tr></table></body></html>";
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setText(htmlContent);
            JInternalFrame jn = new JInternalFrame("I want jlabel here",true,true,true);
jn.add(label);
            jn.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            jn.add(new JButton("JButton"));
            jn.setVisible(true);
            add(jn);
        }
    }

    public class JavaApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {     
            JInternalFrameTest jn = new JInternalFrameTest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You made your `JLabel`, but you never added it to your `JInternalFrame`...

Comment: Plus one for the concise [mcve].

Comment: @Kevin Anderson , Edited my post (I want JLabel in place of header)

Comment: I suggest you have a good look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) for `JInternalFrame`.  If you can tell me which constructor accepts a `JLabel` (or any superclass of `JLabel` such as `Container`) as its first argument, I'll let you have your label in place of the header.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson , Iam just trying to add JLabel  in place of header , I don't know whether it is possible or not. If not possible , is it possible to add a small HTML like table in Header in any way ?

Comment: You can only pass a `String` to specify a title to go in the frame header; probably only a single line of text and I doubt it would support HTML.  You could try passing the HTML for your table, though, and see what happens.  Just be prepared for disappointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like an issue due to inattentive - just add your `label` to `jn` control:

```
jn.add(label);
```

Here is the result of fix (I have also added `<tr><td>sdfsdfsf</td></tr>` to your table.
[image]

**UPD**:
After several clarifications in question it was decided that this new label should be added into title bar of the `JInternalFrame`. It can be also done:

```
void setJInternalFrame() {
     String htmlContent = "<html><body><table border ='1' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>"
                + "<tr><td>Hai</td></tr></table></body></html>";

     JInternalFrame jn = new JInternalFrame("I want jlabel here", true, true, true);

     JComponent titleBar = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) jn.getUI()).getNorthPane();

     JLabel label = new JLabel();
     label.setText(htmlContent);
     label.setBounds(128, 0, 40, 20);
     titleBar.add(label);

     jn.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     jn.add(new JButton("JButton"));
     jn.setVisible(true);
     add(jn);
}
```

The result will be following:

[image]

For changing the height for the title bar you can use following command:

```
titleBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(titleBar.getPreferredSize().width, 100));
// don't forget to set a proper size for the label
label.setBounds(128, 10, 40, 100);
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: I Want this (sdfsdfsc) in place of Header ,Not in the body.

Comment: @srinivas you would like to have it above the JButton? It depends on how you will write your html. My html was just an example, because your even didn't contain cells. =)

Comment: In the mentioned screenshot ,I want HTML table in place of (I want jlabel here) ,not above the Jbutton or beside of it, can you please suggest if possible?

Comment: Thanks for the update, It works ,and small question Can we increase size of header .

Comment: ,I am unable to see table data properly in header if I have one more row in that html ,If I can resize header then I can see data properly.Please suggest if any?

Comment: @srinivas Yes, you can - titleBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(titleBar.getPreferredSize().width, 100));